# Vue + Vuetify - Change v-col size depending on content

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In order to keep it simple i'm going to post a simplified version of what i need to do.

Assuming I've the following component

```html
<template>
  <div style="width: 50vw; height: 40vh;">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row  style="background-color: #222222" class="fill-height">
        <v-col cols="12" lg="8" xl="8" style="background-color: #ff0000"><h1>Breakpoint: {{$vuetify.breakpoint.name}}</h1></v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" lg="4" xl="4" style="background-color: #00FF00"><v-img  src="https://picsum.photos/256/256" min-height="256px" min-width="256px" max-height="256px" max-width="256px"/></v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

Here is how it looks like on the  browser:

[image: XL]
[image: LG-1]

Here is where it starts to break.
[image: LG-2]

[image: MD]
[image: SM]
[image: XS]

I need to have a responsive column that have a inside component with a fixed width and height.

Is there any thing that i can do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a number of `col` widths for the first column it'll automatically try and use all the remaining space.  `cols="auto"` can be used on the second column which will provide enough space for whatever content is inside.  Together I believe they will accomplish your desired responsiveness.  See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-sem5nl?file=/src/App.vue) as an example. Note the example also uses `overflow-wrap: anywhere;` on the h1 text to further prevent wrapping columns until absolutely necessary

Comment: this approach almost does what i need, the main problem is that when i arrives in md breakpoint i wanted that the cols to fill the row. I mean each col with 12 size